# methods/computed cant access data in vue component

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuex

I have a simple vue component where i defined a boolean constant in data with start value false. I now want to create a method to change it to true and bind certain stuff conditionally to that in the template when it changes. But somehow i get the error "property value does not exist on type...". when i move computed out of data i get "Property 'computed' has no initializer"

```
export default class Something extends Vue {
  data() {
    return {
      value: false,
      computed: {
        valueTransform() {
          this.value = true
          alert(this.value)
        },
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't update other data inside computed property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax is not valid in class components, you should have something like :

```js
export default class Something extends Vue {
 
    //data
      value = false,
     
    //computed 
       get valueTransform(){
        return this.value
      }
}
```